# HIghmap colorAxis filter

Tags: highcharts

is it possible to customize colorAxis to have an inbuilt rangeSelector, moving which should set max/min property on colorAxis and in this way help people focus on specific range of values on dense HighMaps?

Eg. lets assume Data range to be [0,100], when chart loads the min=0, max=100 but colorAxis has these range selectors (initially left one on 0 and right one on 100). Now if I move the left input to 30 and right to 70, then the colorAxis min/max property is set to 30/70. As a result on HighMap only the data within this range is colored and rest is either black or white. i think current default is white i tried in a fiddle

```
colorAxis: [{
    min: 100,
    //max: 110,
    //startOnTick: true,
    minColor: '#FFFFFF',
    maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
}, {
    maxColor: '#ff1100'
}],
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x6wtqp4a/1/

**Update**

[image: Range Selector on ColorAxis whihc is draggable in either direction]

Range Selector on ColorAxis which is draggable in either direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stops` property to define the colors for points out of the range:

```
colorAxis: [{
    min: 60,
    max: 110,
    endOnTick: false,
    startOnTick: false,
    stops: [
        [0.001, '#fff'],
        [0.001, '#c4ffd4'],
        [0.999, '#00a82d'],
        [0.999, '#000']
    ]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qsy5e8nk/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/colorAxis.stops

Comment: Sorry maybe my question was not clear. I wanted to turn colorAxis to a rangeSelector like shown in the Update image which should dynamically set the stops based on range selected. Is it possible to make?

Comment: Hi @user4772933, Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wf5L8a2s/

Comment: awesome, and thanks i will accept the answer. Could you please guide me if I were to put a rangeSlider like this https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range behind the colorAxis and plugin your solution. how would it go? Any support on this would be great. but thanks for your help already.

Comment: Sure, here is what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ucfgtjd9/