# HIghmap colorAxis filter dynamic binding

Tags: highcharts

I have some queries extending my previous question [HIghmap colorAxis filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58956494/highmap-coloraxis-filter)

Since my chart can have multiple colorAxis which are decided at run time I want to extend colorAxis dynamically to bind itself with Jquery-Ui range selector for each colorAxis

1. In the solution provided previously on SO, the range selector is placed out of the chart. is it possible to overlay colorAxis on the rangeSelector like in this picture?

[image]

2. Instead of hard-coding the stop colors

`colorAxis: {
            endOnTick: false,
            startOnTick: false,
            stops: [
                [0.001, '#fff'],
                [0.001, '#c4ffd4'],
                [0.999, '#00a82d'],
                [0.999, '#000']
            ]
        },`

I tried to use colorAxis.toColor to get the color at the min/max and set the stops but the color is not changing as expected.

3. Since the colorAxis are dynamically drawn from the data, how to set the step size of range selector dynamically so that the interaction is smooth? for instance. 1 colorAxis could have dataRange from 0-1 while other could be 0-1000 , hence how to set step dynamically for smooth experience?

Your help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

fiddle here that i worked on https://jsfiddle.net/jcy02o9a/

**UPDATE**
For point 2, solution provided below is not correct.

```
 ca.update({
              stops: [
                [stop1, '#fff'],
                [stop1, ca.legendColor.stops[1].color.input],
                [stop2, ca.legendColor.stops[2].color.input],
                [stop2, '#000']
              ]
            })
```

Look at the below animation. Inside the black rectangle at 100 mark. the color is changing as the slider moves. Which means as the slider moves the color for value 100 keeps changing. This is wrong and the color should be fixed to original color. Just that the values with min/max less/greater than range selector should go white/black
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So:

1. Here is an example of how to achieve it:

   ```
     events: {
      render() {
        let slider = document.getElementById('slider-price'),
            chart = this,
            colorAxis = chart.colorAxis[0];

           slider.style.left = (colorAxis.right / 2 + chart.marginRight) + 'px'
      }
   }
   ```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o6jrxy35/1/

2. Here I am not sure what had you have in mind. You need to set initial colors. In the code which you shared stops[2] is a min color and stops[3] is a max color.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zdsbqa73/

3. Is that what you had in mind?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4h1o5ecw/

Comment: thanks for the solution. but colorAxis.right property does not work when there are multiple colorAxis. All colorAxis have same right values so the rangeSelector just end up overlaping each other and poisitoned out of place. check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Ly8pz4we/1/

Comment: check this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0mvnp5ax/

Comment: I came up with a simpler solution `slider.style.left = (ca.legendGroup.translateX + chart.legend.group.translateX) + 'px';`

Comment: Also please check my update, the solution for point 2 that you have provided is also not what I asked and expected. Could you please fix it??

Comment: I don't get it - in my opinion, the suggested solution works exactly the same as the solution from your previous post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58956494/highmap-coloraxis-filter

Comment: Yes it was wrong in previous post let me clarify it. A valid datapoint (one which is within range) should have the same color irrespective of the slider movement. In the solution the color changes. Creating occular illusion. A data point with solid green starts turning lighter green as the left (min) slider is approaching it. It should remain solid green and turn white once the left slider has past it. Not before. https://jsfiddle.net/5r4839s1/ Keep your eye fixed on the rectangles and move the first slider from 0 towards 100 You will notice the color changing, that will cause occular illusion

Comment: A chart is better than a table because more information can be interpreted faster. A naked eye which will relate darker shade to right side of colorAxis, when the slider moves it will start turning lighter, which kind of says that datapoint is loosing value as slider moves. So that is wrong. Either using stops is wrong or setting the color with `ca.legendColor.stops[2].color.input` is wrong. i do not know what is wrong but I hope the problem is clear now. And you agree it is a problem correct?

Comment: I think that I understood what you had in mind... I believe that is it something like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9w7fupk2/

Comment: Yes that is perfect... Could you please help me with one last thing. How does it scale when there are more than 2 stops ? `stops: [
                [0, '#fff'],
                [0, '#c4ffd4'],
                [0.5, '#ffff00'],
                [1, '#00a82d'],
                [1, '#000']
            ]`  like here https://jsfiddle.net/653afcts/ . How would this change the slide function `color1 = H.Color('#c4ffd4').tweenTo(H.Color('#00a82d'), stop1);
            color2 = H.Color('#c4ffd4').tweenTo(H.Color('#00a82d'), stop2);` thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I think that for this use case, the whole concept has to be changed. Something like here will work better: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mn9zvk6b/